# Adding/Removing objects from an array Python

Tags: python, arrays

Please help, in a file I have a function initialize that has an array of data objects inside of it.How can I make a function that can remove a mediaitem when the mediaitem's reference number is input by a user? Also, How can I add a media idea based on what the user inputs?

My function which I need to add/remove items from is:

```
def initialize():
medialist=[
MediaItem("TU2RL012","Movie","2001: A Space Odyssey",11.99, None ,"Stanley Kubrick","Keir Dullea"),
MediaItem("GV5N32M9","Book","A Brief History of Time",10.17,"Stephen Hawking", None, None),
MediaItem("1DB6HK3L","Movie","North by Northwest",8.99, None, "Alfred Hitchcock","Cary Grant"),
MediaItem("PO5T7Y89","Movie", "The Good, The Bad, The Ugly",9.99,None,"Sergio Leone", "Clint Eastwood"),
MediaItem("TR3FL0EW","Book","The Alchemist",6.99,"Paulo Coelho", None,None),
MediaItem("F2O9PIE9", "Book", "Thus Spoke Zarathustra",7.81, "Friedrich Nietzsche", None, None),
MediaItem("R399CED1","Book", "Jonathan Living Seagull",6.97,"Richard Bach", None, None),
MediaItem("2FG6B2N9","Movie", "Gone with the Wind",4.99, "Victor Fleming","Vivien Leigh", None),
MediaItem("6Y9OPL87","Book", "Gone with the Wind",7.99, "Margarett Mitchell", None, None)
]
return medialist
```

To add an item this is what I have coded so far:

```
def create_item():
x=input("Book or Movie?")
for obj in initialize():
    if x== "Movie":
        obj.media="Movie"
        obj.title=input("Enter Movie Title:")
        obj.reference=input("Enter Movie Reference:")
        obj.price=input("Enter Movie Price:")
        obj.director=input("Enter Director Name:")
        obj.lead_actor=input("Enter Lead Actor Name:")
        break

    if x== "Book":
        obj.media="Book"
        obj.title=input("Enter Book Title:")
        obj.reference=input("Enter Book Reference:")
        obj.price=input("Enter Book Price:")
        obj.author=input("Enter Author Name:")
        break
else:
    print("Wrong Input!")
```

Comment: Pls correct your indent first!

Answer (score 0):

Either you can filter the item out of the list and return a new list, or you can find the item's index and remove it from the existing array by reference.

```
def remove(mid, media_list):

    # option 1: filter it out
    # does not remove by reference, returns new array

    return list(filter(lambda item: item.mid != mid))

    # option 2: remove by reference
    # removes by reference, does not return new array

    for i in range(len(media_list)):
        if media_list[i].mid == mid:
            media_list.pop(i)
```

Comment: My issue is it's not a list its an array

Comment: Just make it null then, at index i, rather than popping.

Answer (score 0):

Is `MediaItem` a class? If it is, then items in your array are pointers to objects of that class. If you need to keep it this way, then you will need to write a search method to look for specific objects based on the key in your array.

Assuming you have a method for MediaItems, like MediaItem.getKey() you could do the following...

```
def delete_item(self, key):
    for i in range(len(medialist)):
        if medialist[i].getKey() == key:
            del(l[i])
            return "success"

    return "item not found"
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this:**

```
def delete(item_num, List):
    List = [item for item in List if item_num != item[0] ]
    return List
```

**e.g:**

```
    mylist = delete("GV5N32M9",initialize())
    print(mylist)
```

**The result:**

```
[
        ("TU2RL012","Movie","2001: A Space Odyssey",11.99, None ,"Stanley Kubrick","Keir Dullea"),
        ("1DB6HK3L","Movie","North by Northwest",8.99, None, "Alfred Hitchcock","Cary Grant"),
        ("PO5T7Y89","Movie", "The Good, The Bad, The Ugly",9.99,None,"Sergio Leone", "Clint Eastwood"),
        ("TR3FL0EW","Book","The Alchemist",6.99,"Paulo Coelho", None,None),
        ("F2O9PIE9", "Book", "Thus Spoke Zarathustra",7.81, "Friedrich Nietzsche", None, None),
        ("R399CED1","Book", "Jonathan Living Seagull",6.97,"Richard Bach", None, None),
        ("2FG6B2N9","Movie", "Gone with the Wind",4.99, "Victor Fleming","Vivien Leigh", None),
        ("6Y9OPL87","Book", "Gone with the Wind",7.99, "Margarett Mitchell", None, None)
    ]
```

Comment: since my function is an array I can't do this. How could I add an item?

Comment: Update your post with an example